# Trying to install program as non-admin user but Windows 2008 doesn't accept admin password

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am running Win 2008 Standard Ed. I am logged in as a user (non-admin) and am trying to install a program (via an install.exe file). Windows will prompt for an Admin userid and password which I do enter correctly, but it doesn't accept the credentials and keeps re-prompting for admin user and pass.

I am able to log onto the system with the admin user and password and run the executable installer. Any idea why Windows is not accepting the admin credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Is the machine joined to an Active Directory domain?  If so, you might be inadvertently trying to use the **domain's** administrator account instead of the local system.  Prefix the username in the dialog box with a `.\` so it looks like `.\administrator`. That will tell Windows you want to use the local administrator explicitly.